# Fill existing variables based on their column names and an other variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, search, tibble

My question seems simple and a lot of similar things have been asked already, but i haven't found something combing questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423943/fill-data-frame-by-matching-value-with-column-name) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423943/fill-data-frame-by-matching-value-with-column-name), where i do want to fill existing variables based on their column names and! an other variable. I posted some test code to showcase the problem:

```
require(tibble)
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- as.tibble(data.frame("ID"=rep(1:10,3), "Stuff"=rep(c("A","B","C"),10),"Target"=runif(30)))
dat2 <-  as.tibble(data.frame("ID"=1:10, "A"=rep(NA,10), "B"=rep(NA,10), "C"=rep(NA,10) ) )
```

I would like to fill the columns in dat2 with the values in "Target" based on "ID" and "Stuff" from dat1.
I think it has to some combination of the to linked problems.

(My regular dataset does include about 20 columns to be filled in and about 20'000 datapoints in dat1.)

Comment: You can reshape `dat1` to wide format : `tidyr::pivot_wider(dat1, names_from = Stuff, values_from = Target)`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot, very clean, great comment!